# SharePoint calendar on home page displaying only in IE

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-addin

I've added my calendar to my SharePoint site home page as a web part and edited the web part to display the correct view. From the home page in internet explorer everything is functional.

My problem is when trying to access the home page from a browser other than IE. The calendar becomes unresponsive and shows no useful information as shown here[image: as shown here from google chrome].

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Move the WebPart to a non Rich-text WebPartZone or try in a publishing page.
WebParts added into Rich text zone causes JavaScript issues in Site Pages